# Get the domain name of the user of ADSI object?

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, adsi

In the following script, it will print all the users of the groups. However, the domain name is missing (Some users are in different Windows domain)?

```
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$server,computer"

$computer.psbase.children | ? { 
    $_.psbase.schemaClassName -eq 'group'
} | % {
    $gn = $_.name.ToString()
    write-host $gn

    write-host "------"
    $group =[ADSI]$_.psbase.Path
    $group.psbase.Invoke("Members") | % {
        $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please do not move the target. If you have a new question: ask a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try fetching the SID instead of the name and translate that back to a username:

```
$computer.psbase.children | ? {
    $_.psbase.schemaClassName -eq 'group'
} | % {
    $gn = $_.name.ToString()
    write-host $gn

    write-host "------"
    $group =[ADSI]$_.psbase.Path
    $group.psbase.Invoke("Members") | % {
        $bytes = $_.GetType().InvokeMember('objectSid', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
        $sid = New-Object Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ($bytes, 0)
        $sid.Translate([Security.Principal.NTAccount])
    }
}
```

The result should include the computer or domain name.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar issue where there are accounts from different domains on the computers and we need the domain back. Unfortunately the SID fetch doesn't work I think for local accounts and the domains the computer used to be joined to in some cases, so it didn't return all results.

This was the best solution I found for us:

```
Admin = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("AdsPath", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
```

will return results like

```
WinNT://#domain#/#account#
```

or `WinNT://#domain of computer#/#computer-name#/#account#`

for local accounts

```
$servers= get-content 'C:\temp\work\localadmins\serverlist_in.txt'
$output = 'C:\temp\work\localadmins\serverlist_out.csv' 
$results = @()

foreach($server in $servers)
{
    $admins = @()
    $group =[ADSI]"WinNT://$server/Administrators" 
    $members = @($group.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
    $members | foreach {
       $obj = new-object psobject -Property @{
           Server = $Server
           Admin = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("AdsPath", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
       }
       $admins += $obj
    } 
    $results += $admins
}
$results | Export-csv $Output -NoTypeInformation
```